# sql oracle select group by

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, max

I have two tables by names `CASTR` and `CABL`. My query is

```
SELECT to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5))
      ,MAX(CABL_REL_DAY)
      ,CASTR_KW_CAAC
      ,cabl_avail_bal
FROM CASTR 
INNER JOIN CABL 
    ON CASTR_KW_CAAC = CABL_KW_CAAC
WHERE CABL_REL_DAY <= to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5))   
GROUP BY CASTR_OPER_DATE, CASTR_KW_CAAC, cabl_avail_bal
```

when I run this query it gives me all `cabl_avail_bal` columns, but I want only `cabl_avail_bal`  which their `cabl_rel_day` is max 
and `CABL_REL_DAY<=to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE,1,5))` condition is true.

Here is my table structures

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9NUaysp.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/h9nYwqV.png]

Comment: Please provide table structure with constraints detail. In that way we can provide help more specifically. if that is not possible because of privacy policy, make a similar table and edit your current query to match the table column names.

Comment: could you add something like WHERE CABL_REL_DAY = (select max(CABL_REL_DAY) FROM ..)

Comment: i added table structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using analytic functions, something like this:

```
SELECT to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5)), CABL_REL_DAY, CASTR_KW_CAAC, cabl_avail_bal
FROM (SELECT CASTR_OPER_DATE, CABL_REL_DAY, CASTR_KW_CAAC, cabl_avail_bal,
             row_number() over (partition by CASTR_KW_CAAC order by cable_rel_day desc) as seqnum
      FROM CASTR INNER JOIN
           CABL 
           ON CASTR_KW_CAAC = CABL_KW_CAAC
      WHERE CABL_REL_DAY <= to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5))   
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below

```
WITH CABL_REL_DAY_MAX
  as 
      (SELECT to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5)) oper_date
      ,MAX(CABL_REL_DAY) cabl_rel_max
      ,CASTR_KW_CAAC

      FROM CASTR 
      INNER JOIN CABL 
      ON CASTR_KW_CAAC = CABL_KW_CAAC
      WHERE CABL_REL_DAY <= to_number(substr(CASTR_OPER_DATE, 1, 5))   
      GROUP BY CASTR_OPER_DATE, CASTR_KW_CAAC)
   select oper_date,
          cabl_rel_max,
          CASTR_KW_CAAC,
          CABL.cabl_avail_bal
  FROM CABL 
  INNER JOIN CABL_REL_DAY_MAX
  ON  CASTR_KW_CAAC = CABL_KW_CAAC
  WHERE CABL.CABL_REL_DAY=cabl_rel_max;
```

Comment: psaraj12  , query result is same